# What is the purpose of method classof in clang?

Tags: c++, clang

Let me give you an example to explain what I would like to do (or at least know if this is something that's possible to do) :

In Clang, let's take some basic [ValueDecl](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ValueDecl.html). As you can see on the provided link, this `ValueDecl` can either :

- Be a simple `ValueDecl`
- Be a [DeclaratorDecl](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1DeclaratorDecl.html)
- Be an [EnumConstantDecl](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1EnumConstantDecl.html)
- Be an [IndirectFieldDecl](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1IndirectFieldDecl.html)
- Be an [UnresolvedValueDecl](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1UnresolvedUsingValueDecl.html)

I would like to know if, given a `ValueDecl *`, I can determine whether it's one of the above listed class, or am I bounded to this `ValueDecl *` ?

In every class, there is this [bool classof()](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ValueDecl.html#a23d1635cfe0f09e3bdc5d7948853f18b) method, but I don't understand the purpose of this method. Could it be a solution to my problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`classof` is indeed part of the solution, it is however not normally meant for direct use.

Instead you should be using the [`isa<>`, `cast<>` and `dyn_cast<>` templates](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#isa). An example from the LLVM Programmer's Manual:

```
static bool isLoopInvariant(const Value *V, const Loop *L) {
  if (isa<Constant>(V) || isa<Argument>(V) || isa<GlobalValue>(V))
    return true;

  // Otherwise, it must be an instruction...
  return !L->contains(cast<Instruction>(V)->getParent());
}
```

The difference between `cast<>` and `dyn_cast<>` is that the former asserts if the instance cannot be cast whereas the former merely returns a null pointer.

Note: `cast<>` and `dyn_cast<>` do not allow for a null argument, you can use the `cast_or_null<>` and `dyn_cast_or_null<>` if the argument may be null.

---

For further insights into the design of polymorphism without `virtual` methods, see [How is LLVM `isa<>` implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038330/how-is-llvm-isa-implemented/6068950#6068950), you will note it uses `classof` behind the scenes.